# Can't copy Russian (Cyrillic or Unicode) symbols using SendInput(Edit1.Text)

Tags: delphi, unicode, character-encoding, delphi-7, sendinput

```
procedure SendText(ds:string);
var
  TI: TInput;
  KI: TKeybdInput;
  i: integer;
begin
  TI.Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  for i := 1 to Length(ds) do
  begin
    KI.wVk := Ord(UpCase(ds[i]));
    KI.dwFlags := 0;
    TI.ki := KI;
    SendInput(1, TI, SizeOf(TI));
    KI.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    TI.ki := KI;
    SendInput(1, TI, SizeOf(TI));
  end;
end;
```

How can I add Unicode? Any suggestions how to copy Russian (Cyrilic) symbols using `SendInput(Edit1.Text);`

Comment: UI Automation or MSAA is what you want.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx MSDN docs are pretty obvious

Comment: @TLama Ok, I'll try it now. Where i must put *.pas file?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4363/discussion-between-yurios-and-tlama)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In this example I've used unit [JclUnicode.pas](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid82A72B784CB8F3DF2489C1FE4FCCEB4C9621DBED.aspx) from [JEDI project](http://www.delphi-jedi.org/). If you have Delphi 6 up then you can omit the JclUnicode in the uses clause.

```
uses
  JclUnicode;

procedure SendText(const Value: WideString);
var
  I: Integer;
  S: WideString;
  TI: TInput;
  KI: TKeybdInput;
const
  KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = $0004;
begin
  S := WideUpperCase(Value); 
  TI.Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    KI.wVk := 0;
    KI.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    KI.wScan := Ord(S[I]);
    TI.ki := KI;
    SendInput(1, TI, SizeOf(TI));
  end;
end;
```

Comment: SendText('UPPER lower 1234567890 /*-+!"£$%^&*()_+= ąčęėįšųūž'); results in UER LOWER 1234567890 /*-+!"£$%^&*()_+= ĄČĘĖĮŠŲŪŽŽ in XE2.

Comment: double keys like P in UPPER are not showing up. We need to release the key to generate another one. See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

```
uses
  JclUnicode;

procedure SendText(const Value: WideString);
var
  I: Integer;
  S: WideString;
  TI: TInput;
  KI: TKeybdInput;
const
  KEYEVENTF_UNICODE = $0004;
begin
  S := WideUpperCase(Value); 
  TI.Itype := INPUT_KEYBOARD;
  for I := 1 to Length(S) do
  begin
    KI.wVk := 0;
    KI.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;
    KI.wScan := Ord(S[I]);
    TI.ki := KI;
    SendInput(1, TI, SizeOf(TI));

    // release keys to avoid double key missing (like P in UPPER)
    KI.dwFlags := KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    TI.ki := KI;
    SendInput(1, @TI, SizeOf(TI));     
  end;
end;
```